# React component breakdown strategy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I need to implement components tree on React.

And I'm wondering what is good enough pattern how to break everything in tree
but with scaling(code or team) in mind.

Usually I'm using next way:

```
function UserAvatar(props) {
  return <div><img src="" alt="" /></div>   
}

function UserEmail(props) {
  return <div>e-mail: some@email.com</div>   
}

function UserSection(props) {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="section">
        <UserAvatar />
      </div>
      <div className="section">
        <UserEmail />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But should I avoid all this layout divs and make layout cleaner?

One obvious option is to move into the separate component layout stuff.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Guidelines on breaking down components:

1. When your component is doing too much. Components should ideally be focused on doing one (or a few, but not many) things. The most obvious sign is when the number of lines in the code is getting too long. As a rough estimate, components should not be more than 300 lines.
2. When you want to reuse components across multiple parent components, you'll have to break them up.
3. If you want to optimize the `render()` of specific subtrees of a componant via `shouldComponentUpdate()`, then you have to break them up as you can only implement `shouldComponentUpdate()` on the component-level.
4. Separating data fetching logic from rendering and handling user interactions logic. Instead of making one component do both data fetching and (rendering and handling user interactions), break them down into smaller components so that you can test the components separately:

   - Test that the first component fetches data.
   - Test that the second component renders the data properly and can respond to user interactions.
   - Read more about it [here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)

Many more good answers by Kent C. Dodds [here](https://blog.kentcdodds.com/when-to-break-up-a-component-into-multiple-components-4ee75ab53bbc).

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to keep each `Component` in their own files then import them where you need to reference them.

Also, in your example it's most likely you'll need to set the avatar url and email as props. Then make the `UserAvatar` and `UserEmail` render the values. Also, it's good practice to setup the propTypes, so other developers (and yourself) know which props to pass.

One criteria to break down components into subcomponents it's when they deal with different concerns, or when the file size is getting too large. Another criteria is when you need to re-use that component in some other context.

Hope this helps.